# PHP сделать 3 проверки в return вместо 1?

Tags: php, return

Сейчас есть код: return ($doc->find('div#someid')->length() > 0);
который проверяет, что нужный id существует на странице и если существует, возвращает 1

Необходимо расширить код ещё 2 проверками, чтобы дополнительно проверялось, что:

.class1 не содержит текст "Предложений" и .class2 не содержит текст "Проект закрыт"

Answer (score 1):

Нужно воспользоваться [логическими операторами](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/language.operators.logical.php)

```
return ($doc->find('div#someid')->length() > 0) 
   and !str_contains($doc->find('.class1'), 'Предложений')
   and !str_contains($doc->find('.class2'), 'Проект закрыт');
```

Comment: В моём случае оказалось достаточно проверить 1 поле, просто другое (его наличие сразу проверяло по трём параметрам), но не по содержимому текста, так не работало, а по условию что тег не пустой, вот так сработало и возвращает 1:
return ($doc->find('.class')->length() > 0);

Спасибо за помощь.